# Skill allocation

Tags: phrase-requests

What do you call the process of putting people in the best place to complete a goal? Ex. If one person is better at A than B, and another person is also better at A than B but is better at both than the first person, person 1 does A and person 2 does B

Comment: perhaps "skill based deployment"

Comment: Sounds similar to a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: I think skill-based [allocation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allocate) is fine. Why does that not work?

Comment: I just thought there was a different phrase for it

Comment: "human capital/resources optimization": [The right employee in the right position at the right time and location for the right cost](http://www.sas.com/resources/asset/5stepstooptimization.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Use **division of labor** to mean assigning chores based on efficiency to different workers.

[Dictionary of Unfamiliar Words by Diagram Group:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/division+of+labor)

> The division of production into separate processes each of which is performed by different people.